# Where in the Airflow UI can I add the aws connections?

Tags: airflow

In this [example](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/example_dags/example_emr_job_flow_manual_steps.py), I see that the EmrCreateJobFlowOperator receives  the aws/emr connections that were setup in Airflow UI:

```
cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
   task_id='create_job_flow',
   job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
   aws_conn_id='aws_default',
   emr_conn_id='emr_conn_id',
   dag=dag)
```

In Airflow UI, in the tabs of connections, how can I add my AWS credentials so the DAG can pick them up? I don't see any type of connections for AWS. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aws_default` picks up credentials from environment variables or `~/.aws/credentials`. You can choose your deployment mode as decide where you want to put the secret.

However if you want to add a connection string via UI, you can go to Admin -> Connections and edit the keys there.

Comment: Which environment variables?